# Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, scripting

I have two `*.sql` files that I use when creating a new web site database.  The first file creates all the tables.  The second file populates some default records.  I would like to execute these files from PHP.  I also use the Zend_Framework, if that will help accomplish this.

**Additional Info**

1. I don't have console access
2. I'm trying to automate site generation from within our application.

**SOLUTION**

Using `shell_exec()`...

```
$command = 'mysql'
        . ' --host=' . $vals['db_host']
        . ' --user=' . $vals['db_user']
        . ' --password=' . $vals['db_pass']
        . ' --database=' . $vals['db_name']
        . ' --execute="SOURCE ' . $script_path
;
$output1 = shell_exec($command . '/site_db.sql"');
$output2 = shell_exec($command . '/site_structure.sql"');
```

...I never did get useful output, but followed [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814586/calling-mysql-exe-using-php-exec-doesnt-work/814722#814722) on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814586/calling-mysql-exe-using-php-exec-doesnt-work) and finally got it all working.  I switch to the `--option=value` format for the commands and used `--execute="SOURCE ..."` instead of `<` to execute the file.

Also, I never got a good explanation of the difference between `shell_exec()` and `exec()`.

Comment: You can't use the console? It's that much easier....

Comment: worked great for me on linux. havent tried it on windows xampp, but it doubt it will work :)

Comment: The difference between `shell_exec()` and `exec()` is that `shell_exec` returns all of the output stream as a string. `exec` returns the last line of the output. via http://stackoverflow.com/a/7093892/557358

Comment: Here is a very good solution I have come up with http://stackoverflow.com/a/41404203/627473

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This question comes up from time to time.  There's no good solution for running a .sql script directly from PHP.  There are edge cases where statements common in a .sql script can't be executed as SQL statements.  For example, the mysql tool has [builtin commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html) that are not recognized by the MySQL Server, e.g. `CONNECT`, `TEE`, `STATUS`, and `DELIMITER`.

So I give +1 to @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php/4027786#4027786).  You should run your .sql script in PHP by invoking the `mysql` tool, for instance with [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec).

---

I got this test working:

```
$command = "mysql --user={$vals['db_user']} --password='{$vals['db_pass']}' "
 . "-h {$vals['db_host']} -D {$vals['db_name']} < {$script_path}";

$output = shell_exec($command . '/shellexec.sql');
```

---

See also my answers to these related questions:

- [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456)
- [is it possible to call a sql script from a stored procedure in another sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547915/is-it-possible-to-call-a-sql-script-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-sql-script/548119#548119)
- [PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql_query statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement/345712#345712)

Comment: I am trying the shell_exec() route, but I am not finding examples specifying a file to execute.  This is what I have so far: `shell_exec('mysql' . ' -u ' . $vals['db_user'] . ' -p ' . $vals['db_pass'] . ' -D ' . $vals['db_name']);`

Comment: You read the file to execute with shell redirection: `mysql ... < mysqldump.sql`

Comment: I thought I would offer some insight into anyone reading this who couldn't get it to work, One issue that can occur with shell_exec is that `mysql` is not on the path. This is easy to test by running the command `mysql` in the console of the affected machine. In this case, MySQL would need to be added to the path or an alternate approach would be required.

Comment: @AaronNewton, good idea. Path-related issues are pretty basic, but I forget how many people still struggle with them.

Comment: What If I need to create a database as well?

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava You can put `CREATE DATABASE <database>` and `USE <database>` statements into the top of the SQL script file. Or alternatively, you can execute a CREATE DATABASE statement from PHP first, then run the SQL script as I showed above.

Comment: @LuongTranNguyen, No. I would rather use `--defaults-file` and put the user name and password in that file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html

Answer (score 23):

```
$commands = file_get_contents($location);   
$this->_connection->multi_query($commands);
```

Comment: Your solution works for `mysqli`. I am using PDO. Your answer prompted me to do a search, and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: I'm using mysqli and can't get this solution to work.  $commands just comes back as an empty string.  For $location I have tried both a relative local path (the script file is in the same folder as the php file) and a fully qualified hyperlink.  I get the same result either way.

Comment: This seems to fail for certain types of advanced queries, such as creating a procedure and executing it.

Comment: in case one of queries failed, you will never know

Answer (score 15):

You'll need to create a full SQL parser for this. I recommend you use the `mysql` command line tool for this instead, invoking it externally from PHP.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I use:

---

```
function run_sql_file($location){
    //load file
    $commands = file_get_contents($location);

    //delete comments
    $lines = explode("\n",$commands);
    $commands = '';
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $line = trim($line);
        if( $line && !startsWith($line,'--') ){
            $commands .= $line . "\n";
        }
    }

    //convert to array
    $commands = explode(";", $commands);

    //run commands
    $total = $success = 0;
    foreach($commands as $command){
        if(trim($command)){
            $success += (@mysql_query($command)==false ? 0 : 1);
            $total += 1;
        }
    }

    //return number of successful queries and total number of queries found
    return array(
        "success" => $success,
        "total" => $total
    );
}


// Here's a startsWith function
function startsWith($haystack, $needle){
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}
```

Comment: There are edge-cases where this will fail, and not with an error-message but (potentially) unexpected behavior. For example, multi-line string literals in your SQL statements could start with the string `'--'`, or string literals might contain `;` characters. If you're going to go this route, you really should use a full SQL parser.

Answer (score 8):

I have never had to use it but the mysqli class has a multi_query method:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm pretty late to the party but [PHP Mini Admin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpminiadmin/) has been a lifesaver on a couple of occasions. It's basically a "lite" PHPMyAdmin all contained in one file so no need for complicated installs, just upload it and log in. Simples!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). Pretty solid interface for interacting with MySQL.

I don't know if it solves your problem, since I don't know if you can interact with it directly from code, but just wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: Good suggestion too. Parsing mySQL dumps in pure PHP *sucks*, phpMyAdmin takes the pain out of it (is not automatable, though).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to run MySQL script files. You'll need to set $hostName, $userName, $password, $dataBaseName, $port and $fileName of course.

```
<?php

function parseScript($script) {

  $result = array();
  $delimiter = ';';
  while(strlen($script) && preg_match('/((DELIMITER)[ ]+([^\n\r])|[' . $delimiter . ']|$)/is', $script, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    if (count($matches) > 2) {
      $delimiter = $matches[3][0];
      $script = substr($script, $matches[3][1] + 1);
    } else {
      if (strlen($statement = trim(substr($script, 0, $matches[0][1])))) {
        $result[] = $statement;
      }
      $script = substr($script, $matches[0][1] + 1);
    }
  }

  return $result;

}

function executeScriptFile($fileName, $dbConnection) {
  $script = file_get_contents($scriptFleName);
  $statements = parseScript($script);
  foreach($statements as $statement) {
    mysqli_query($dbConnection, $statement);
  }
}

$hostName = '';
$userName = '';
$password = '';
$dataBaseName = '';
$port = '';
$fileName = '';

if ($connection = @mysqli_connect($hostName, $userName, $password, $dataBaseName, $port)) {
  executeScriptFile($fileName, $connection);
} else {
  die('Can not connect to MySQL');
}
```

Comment: When writing an answer to your own question, could you please post an explanation as well as code.  Without an explanation we still don't know why the problem was fixed without studying a lot of useless code.

Comment: It wasn't my own question. TC asked "I would like to execute these files from PHP". I gave script how to do this. If you are unable to read such small piece of code (there is not much to study, it's too small and obvious), and if you don't need solution - why you can's just skip my answer instead of being such a rude? :)

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude.   See that down-vote above (someone else put it there in case you think it's me)?  I'm trying to tell you *why* you are getting it and suggesting what you can do to get upvotes instead. I'm only trying to help. also it was edited edited 3 min ago and it now looks better.  Unfortunately for newcomers users here expect a fantastic answer (and question) as well as working code.  It's a knack.  Once you have it you will be able to do good answers (and questions) and get upvotes.

Comment: I hope I did not offend, I do not mean to.  As I said above I'm trying to get you some reputation by helping you improve your answers and questions.

Answer (score 1):

I created a migration script with `multi_query`. It can process mysqldump output and phpmyadmin exports without mysql command line tool. I also made some logic to process multiple migration files based on timestamp stored in DB like Rails. I know it needs more error handling but currently does the work for me.

Check it out: https://github.com/kepes/php-migration

I think if you don't process user input with it only scripts made by developers or export tools you can use it safely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution and the below code explains what is does. 
The principle is to read the file line by line, build a query and execute each of them. I saw many solutions using the "file_get_contents" which is not a good solution because it could cause a buffer issue as it read the whole file contents to string variable.
My solution takes also into account TRIGGERs' queries. 
There's no array allocation, comment and empty lines are stripped.

```
<?php
 /**
 * Get a connection from database
 * @param type $db_host database hostname
 * @param type $db_user database username
 * @param type $db_password database password
 * @param type $db_name database name
 * @return \PDO
 */
 function get_db_connection($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)
{
    $dns = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name";
    try
    {
        return new PDO($dns, $db_user, $db_password);
    } catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Runs SQL queries from file
 */

 function exec_sql_queries_from_file($script_file, $db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)
{
    // to increase the default PHP execution time
    set_time_limit ( 60 ); // Max time = 60 seconds

    // Connect to database
    $connection = get_db_connection($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

    // If the connection is acquired
    if($connection != null){

        // Open sql file
        $f = fopen($script_file, 'r');

        // sql query
        $query = '';

        // Default delimiter for queries
        $delimiter = ';';

        // read line by line
        while (!feof($f))
        {           
            $line = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', fgets($f)); // read a line and remove the end of line character

            /* if the current line contains the key word 'DELIMITER'. Ex: DELIMITER ;; or DELIMITER $$
             * mostly used for TRIGGERS' queries
             */
            if(strpos($line, 'DELIMITER') !== false)
            {
                // change the delimiter and read the next line
                $delimiter = str_replace('DELIMITER ', '', $line);
                continue;
            }   

            // Consider the line as part of a query if it's not empty and it's not a comment line
            if (!empty($line) && !starts_with($line, '/*') && !starts_with($line, '--'))
            {
                // the query hasn't reach its end: concatenate $line to $query if $line is not a delimiter
                $query .= $line !== $delimiter ? $line : '';

                // if the current line ends with $delimiter: end of current query
                if (ends_with($line, $delimiter))
                {                
                    // exec the query
                    $connection->exec($query) or die($connection->errorInfo());
                    // start new query
                    $query = '';
                }
            }                    
        }

        fclose($f);
    }
}

 /**
 * Starts with function
 */
function starts_with($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $haystack{0} === $needle{0} ? stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0 : false;
}

/**
 * Ends with function
 */
function ends_with($haystack, $needle)
{
    $pos = stripos($haystack, $needle);
    return $pos === FALSE ? FALSE : substr($haystack, $pos) === $needle;
```

}

Comment: Nice idea, but with some mistakes.
Replaceing eol with nothing.
Search by ; for EOL or end of command (this can also be used in comments) aso.
But again, the idea is great

Answer (score 0):

To execute table generation from within the application, you may want to create a php file that will do just that when you run it.

```
$hostname  = "localhost";
$database  = "databasename";
$username  = "rootuser";
$UserPassword  = "password";

$myconnection = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username , $UserPassword) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_connect($hostname , $username , $UserPassword ) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

if ( !$myconnection ){ echo "Error connecting to database.\n";}


$userstableDrop = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`";
$userstableCreate = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `User_First_Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15" ;

$userstableInsert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`UserID`, `User_First_Name`) VALUES
(1, 'Mathew'),
(2, 'Joseph'),
(3, 'James'),
(4, 'Mary')";

$userstableAlter1 = "ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`)";
$userstableAlter2 = " ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=15";

$createDb_sql = $userstableDrop;
$insertSite = mysql_query($createDb_sql);

$createDb_sql = $userstableCreate;
$insertSite = mysql_query($createDb_sql);

$createDb_sql = $userstableInsert;
$insertSite = mysql_query($createDb_sql);

$createDb_sql = $userstableAlter1;
$insertSite = mysql_query($createDb_sql);

$createDb_sql = $userstableAlter2;
$insertSite = mysql_query($createDb_sql);

echo "Succesful!";
mysql_close($myconnection );
```

Comment: Please see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Just wanna to add to @Bill Karwin answer given above.

You can import | reinitialize | execute custom SQL; the database using sql script file, by simply clicking on button. That button would execute the sql script file using ajax.

eg.

---

Front end code

```
  <input type="button" value="Execute SQL Script" id="btnExecuteScript" />
  <input type="button" value="reset" onclick="clearDiv('divExecuteScript')" />
  <div id="divExecuteScript" style='display: none'></div>
  <br />
```

---

Jquery code calling the ajax

```
  $('#btnExecuteScript').click(function (event) {
    if ($('#divExecuteScript').html() == '') {
      $('#divExecuteScript').html("<b style='font-family: sans-serif;font-size: larger'>Please Wait, It might take a few minutes</b>");
      $('#divExecuteScript').show();
      $.get("../controller/Controller.php?executeScript=TRUE", function (data) {
        // alert("$" + data + "$");
        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
        $('#divExecuteScript').html(data);
        $('#divExecuteScript').show();
      });
    } else
      $('#divExecuteScript').toggle();
  });
```

---

connection file

```
class Conn {

    protected $databaseURL; // const
    protected $databaseName;
    protected $databaseUName;
    protected $databasePWord;
    public $mysqli;

        public function __construct($args = null) {
        if (stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "localhost") !== FALSE) {
                $this->databaseURL = "host"; 
                $this->databaseName = "database";
                $this->databaseUName = "user";
                $this->databasePWord = "password";
            } 
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->databaseURL, $this->databaseUName, $this->databasePWord, $this->databaseName) or die('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

             if (empty($this->mysqli))
               die("Error while connecting to host"); 
    }

    function get_databaseURL() {
        return $this->databaseURL;
    }

    function get_databaseUName() {
        return $this->databaseUName;
    }

    function get_databasePWord() {
        return $this->databasePWord;
    }

    function get_databaseName() {
        return $this->databaseName;
    }

}
```

---

controller code executing the command

```
$con = new Conn();
  $mysqli = new mysqli($con->get_databaseURL(), $con->get_databaseUName(), $con->get_databasePWord(), $con->get_databaseName()) or die('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

if (isset($_GET['executeScript'])) {
  $script_path = '/path-to-script-file/filename.sql';
  $command = "mysql --user={$con->get_databaseUName()} --password='{$con->get_databasePWord()}' "
  . "-h {$con->get_databaseURL()} -D {$con->get_databaseName()} < {$script_path}";
  $output = shell_exec($command);

  if (!empty($output))
    echo "<b style='font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large'>Execute the SQL script<br />";
  else
    echo "<b style='font-family: sans-serif;font-size: large'>Unable to execute the SQL script</b><br />";

  return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**PHP Code**

The code I found on [this](https://phppot.com/php/how-to-import-sql-into-a-database-using-php/) page worked for me.
*(Scroll down to see the commented version)*

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'sql_auto_test_table');

$query = ''; 
$sqlScript = file('sqlFileName.sql');

foreach ($sqlScript as $line)   {

    $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0 ,2);
    $endWith = substr(trim($line), -1 ,1);
    
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '--' || $startWith == '/*' || $startWith == '//') {
        continue;
    }
    
    $query = $query . $line . "/*<br>*/"; 
    if ($endWith == ';') {
        mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('<div>Problem in executing the SQL query <b>,<br><br>' . $query. '</b><br><br>'.$conn->error.'</div>');
        $query= '';     
    }
}
echo '<div>SQL file imported successfully</div>';
?>
```

---

**Potential Fixes**

I tested this file with a *WordPress database* **exported to SQL** using *phpMyAdmin* and it worked fine. I had to add the following lines at the top of the .sql file to avoid a few **DEFAULT VALUE errors** in some DATE columns. Alternatively, you can try executing the following queries before executing your SQL file if you receive a similar error.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

In addition, substitute the violent die() function with a better error-handling mechanism.

---

**Explanation**

In case you want, I added a few comment lines to explain the behavior.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'db_name');

$query = ''; //Set an empty query variable to hold the query
$sqlScript = file('mySqlFile.sql'); //Set the sql file location

//Read each line of the file
foreach ($sqlScript as $line)   {

    //Get the starting character and the ending character of each line
    $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0 ,2);
    $endWith = substr(trim($line), -1 ,1);
    
    //Check for empty or comment lines. (If the line starts with --,/*,// or the line is empty, skip to the next line)
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '--' || $startWith == '/*' || $startWith == '//') {
        continue;
    }
    
    //Add the line to the query. (Additional optional commented out <br> tag added to query for easy error identification)
    $query = $query . $line . "/*<br>*/"; 
    //If the line end with a ";" assume the last query has ended in this line
    if ($endWith == ';') {
        //Therefore, try to execute the query. Upon failure, display the last formed query with the SQL error message
        mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('<div>Problem in executing the SQL query <b>,<br><br>' . $query. '</b><br><br>'.$conn->error.'</div>');
        //Reset the query variable and continue to loop the next lines
        $query= '';     
    }
}
//If nothing went wrong, display a success message after looping through all the lines in the sql file
echo '<div>SQL file imported successfully</div>';

/*
If failed with an invalid DEFAULT value for a DATE column error, try adding the following lines to the top of your SQL file. Otherwise, execute these lines before executing your .sql file.
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
*/
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the easy solution, that's works for me

```
$new_conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","pass","db_name");
$quries=file_get_contents("db_backup.sql");
$res=mysqli_multi_query($new_conn,$quries);
```

Comment: in case one of queries failed, you will never know

Comment: besides, such answer already exists

Answer (score -2):

One suggestion:

```
// connect to db.
if (mysql_query("SOURCE myfile.sql")) {

  echo "Hello Sonny";

}
```

Comment: If this works (will depend on privileges) it is definitely the single best way to go.

Comment: No, `SOURCE` is a builtin of the mysql tool. You can't execute it as an SQL query.

Comment: `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries

Comment: There are ways around it. but, please be very mindful about the queries; if not careful, the are prone to sql injection. Have a read of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/multiple-mysql-queries