# What are the differences of system(), exec() and shell_exec() in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, system, exec, shell-exec

It is possible to run an external command by three PHP functions of

```
system();
exec();
shell_exec();
```

but what are their differences? In spite of their specific applications, in most cases, the can be equally used. I am curious to know which is preferred one when they can be equally used. For example, for unzipping a file or compressing a folder (with tar command), which one is preferred (probably from performance point of view)?

**UPDATE:** In another question, I found a very useful **[link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130809032648/http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@)** describing different aspects for these functions. I share the link here, as other may use to better understand security issues and other aspects.

Comment: Not to be snippy, but what did the manual say about the respective functions?

Comment: Also, you forgot passthru () :)

Comment: @GordonM I read the manual, but I do not understand the preference for each function. For many cases, they can be equally used. I want a practical view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Comment: @periklis you're right, that question addresses the same issue, but I was unable to find it. One answer has a quite useful link for detailed explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/732832/608639) and [php shell\_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) — Execute an external program

[system](http://php.net/system) — Execute an external program and display the output

[shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec) — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

so if you don't need the output, I would go with exec.

Further details:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
- http://php.net/shell_exec

Comment: `exec()` returns the last line of output, so if you're calling a simple program that just outputs a single value like `whoami` or `pwd`, `exec()` is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on the existing answer with examples:

All functions will attempt to execute the command almost as if from the terminal. The main difference is in the output and error handling:

### **exec()**

*Outputs to var only the last line; Outputs array with each line to 2nd arg; Outputs `result_code` to 3rd arg -- any non-zero `result_code` is an error. Here's [a list of result_codes](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html)*

```php
$last_line = exec('pwd;ls -alh', $all_lines_array, $result_code);
echo "LAST_LINE: $last_line";
print_r($all_lines_array);
echo "RESULT_CODE: $result_code";

/*
LAST_LINE: -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln 1.2K Feb  7 03:43 index.php 

Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir/subdir
    [1] => total 20K
    [2] => drwxr-xr-x 3 root         root   4.0K Feb  7 03:17 .
    [3] => drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  6 21:46 ..
    [4] => -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln  550 Feb  6 22:45 .htaccess
    [5] => drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  7 00:22 cache
    [6] => -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln 1.2K Feb  7 03:43 index.php
)

RESULT_CODE: 0
*/
```

### **shell_exec()**

*Outputs single or multiline plain text to var. Takes only 1 arg -- the command*

```php
$plain_text = shell_exec('pwd;ls -alh');
echo $plain_text;

/*
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir/subdir
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root         root   4.0K Feb  7 03:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  6 21:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln  550 Feb  6 22:45 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  7 00:22 cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln 1.2K Feb  7 03:43 index.php
*/
```

### **system()**

*Echos single or multiline plain text. No need for `echo system();`. `result_code` is the same as `exec()`*

```php
system('pwd;ls -alh',$result_code);
echo "RESULT_CODE: $result_code";
/*
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir/subdir
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root         root   4.0K Feb  7 03:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  6 21:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln  550 Feb  6 22:45 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  7 00:22 cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln 1.2K Feb  7 03:43 index.php

RESULT_CODE: 0
*/
```

### **Backtick quotes ``**

*Basically, alias for `shell_exec()`. Outputs single or multiline plain text to var*

```php
$plain_text = `pwd;ls -al`;
echo $plain_text;

/*
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir/subdir
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root         root   4.0K Feb  7 03:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  6 21:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln  550 Feb  6 22:45 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu psacln 4.0K Feb  7 00:22 cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu psacln 1.2K Feb  7 03:43 index.php
*/
```

`exec()` appears to be most versatile as you can iterate over the array of lines, get the last line only, and the `result_code`.

`shell_exec()` and backticks `` are great if plain text works better for you.

`system()` echos automatically :(