# What is different between exec(), shell_exec, system() and passthru() functions in PHP?

Tags: php

Anybody please tell me. I want know the different between the `exec()`, `shell_exec`, `system()` and `passthru()` function?

I search from [php.net](http://php.net) unable to get the answers I need.

Comment: As far as I can see, correct description (with differences) are provided for each on PHP webiste. http://uk3.php.net/exec

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828707/what-are-the-differences-of-system-exec-and-shell-exec-in-php

Comment: Can u sey me what is the use of passthru() ? Send me reference link which i will find my answer with example

Comment: From PHP documentation for passthru: "This function should be used in place of exec() or system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which needs to be passed directly back to the browser."

http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Answer (score 97, accepted):

- [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) only returns the last line of the generated output.
- [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) returns the full output of the command, when the command finished running.
- [`system`](http://php.net/system) immediately shows all output, and is used to show text.
- [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) also returns output immediately, but is used for binary data. `passthru` displays raw data.

With both `exec` and `shell_exec` it is possible to handle the output yourself, while `system` and `passthru` won't let you customize it and immediately display the output.

A more detailed comparison can be found [here](http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP:-exec-m@).

Comment: Would be awesome if you had an example

Comment: `system` return false when there was an error. Does this mean when the exit code is `!== 0` it will return false? So I do not have to actually check the `$retval` if I just want to check of the command suceeded?

Answer (score 4):

passthru is used for returning binary data instead of ascii. A typical example is where an image manipulation program is returning an image instead of text data.

See [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru) for more info

Also see [php shell_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec).