# Invoke Weka tool inside PHP application

Tags: php, weka

I am developing a web application to analyse the effect of a persons sleep habits  on his health and performance..Can anyone help me about how to integrate weka tool into my application..for the analysis of data??

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) (or [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php))

For a summary of the differences for these functions, this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072886/3052648