# php shell_exec() executing but I'm not seeing results

Tags: php, git, shell-exec

I know this might sound odd or might probably be a duplicated question but have searched and could not find any possible solutions.

I want to auto-deploy my code from bitbucket to my server. I created an ssh key and linked them, created a bare git folder that the code goes to and then a production folder which carries the live site. I added a webhook to bitbucket that should execute anytime I run a push to my repository. My challenge now is, the script is executed but I don't see any changes, but If I manually write the command in the console, everything works fine. Please help. I'm running a Linode server with a debian 9 OS. 
This is the code from my deployment script. Please help me. I have on this for 4 days now.

```
<?php
$repo_dir = '/var/www/git/_ku1bo__c_plus_z_.git';
$web_root_dir = '/var/www/html/kobuplus.com/public_html';
$git_path = '/usr/bin/git';
exec("cd $repo_dir" && "$git_path fetch");
exec("cd $repo_dir" && "GIT_WORK_TREE=$web_root_dir $git_path checkout -f");
file_put_contents("deploy.log", date("m/d/Y h:i:s a") . "deployed latest branch" . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: Does your webserver has permissions?

Comment: You say `shell_exec` in your question, and use `exec` in your example. Did you know there is a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072696/what-is-different-between-exec-shell-exec-system-and-passthru-functions) and it mainly effects the output handling

Comment: exec, shell_exec, system.  all methods of calling commands, with different return values and parameters.

Comment: And you have a weird syntax here.  `exec("command1" && "command2");`.  This means that php will do `"command1" && "command2"`, so TRUE && TRUE, which === TRUE.  So it will do `exec(TRUE)` ?!?  Makes no sense.   If you want to use && like in a bash shell, do `exec("command1 && command2");`  Exec takes 1 string, which is executed on the system.

Comment: Yes, my webserver have permissions. I have used both `exec` and `shell_exec` but still not working.

Comment: I have adjusted my code to:
`<?php`

`$repo_dir = '/var/www/git/_ku1bo__c_plus_z_.git';`
`$web_root_dir = '/var/www/html/kobuplus.com/public_html';`
`$git_path = '/usr/bin/git';`

`exec("cd $repo_dir && $git_path fetch");`
`exec("cd $repo_dir && GIT_WORK_TREE=$web_root_dir $git_path checkout -f");`

`file_put_contents("deploy.log", date("m/d/Y h:i:s a") . "deployed latest branch" . "\n", FILE_APPEND);`

`?>`
But all to no avail. O don't know what to do anymore. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your joining your string incorrectly, try this:

```
<?php
$repo_dir = '/var/www/git/_ku1bo__c_plus_z_.git';
$web_root_dir = '/var/www/html/kobuplus.com/public_html';
$git_path = '/usr/bin/git';
exec("cd " . $repo_dir . $git_path . " fetch");
exec("cd $repo_dir GIT_WORK_TREE=$web_root_dir $git_path checkout -f");
file_put_contents("deploy.log", date("m/d/Y h:i:s a") . "deployed latest branch" . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: That did not work. The fetch word on line 5 is not in quotes. It will flag error on running the code that way.

Comment: @Atoms Fixed that. But probably still won't work, you're getting commands like: `cd /var/www/git/_ku1bo__c_plus_z_.git/var/www/html/kobuplus.com/public_html` now. What did you originally mean with the `&&`? And which commands are you trying to run in plain text.

Comment: It's a script that I added to bitbucket webhook to automate deployment when I run a push command. So I believe running the command that way using the 'exec()' command will make it run at the terminal. I think my code is correct, i'm actually thinking the issue is coming from somewhere else. Probably permissions. I'm will look into that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

-> Run the file using this command to see how it behaves (using the SSH command line interface):

```
php absolute_path_of_the_file
```

-> If you get this error: `Permission denied (publickey)`, then make sure you have added the SSH key to the repository settings.