# php exec() command doesn't work with other application

Tags: php, command-prompt, imagemagick-convert

I have an application which was developed using `php` and I want to print a dithering image through my printer so what I am doing is I have an application called ImageMagick. In this application using command prompt I will pass an image path and the destination folder. So when I run the command in the command prompt it will convert the image and save it in destination folder.

Firstly I tried the `php exec()` for the below code

```
    <?php
     echo exec('ipconfig');
    ?>
```

The above code gives the output on the browser

When I give the below code:

```
   <?php
     echo exec('date');
   ?>
```

It gives the output as below

```
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)
```

But When I run the `date` command on the command prompt it gives the current date

I tried to run the Imagemagick command in `php` code as shown below

```
<?php
echo exec('convert "C:\bhargav\dev\download.jpg" -resize 384 -dither FloydSteinberg -remap pattern:gray50 "C:\bhargav\dev\con.jpg"');
?>
```

But it doesn't save any image as output and no error is shown on the browser.

```
convert "C:\bhargav\dev\download.jpg" -resize 384 -dither FloydSteinberg -remap pattern:gray50 "C:\bhargav\dev\con.jpg"
```

when the above command is given in the command prompt it gives me the output.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think it could be a lot of things.  It could be file permissions. See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072696/what-is-different-between-exec-shell-exec-system-and-passthru-functions for other options.  You could also benefit from sending stderr to stdout so that you can see any errors that occur.

Comment: Have you checked for [safe mode](https://secure.php.net/manual/features.safe-mode.php)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538939/php-exec-will-not-execute-shell-command-when-executed-via-browser) question also checks a lot of options why exec might not work.

Comment: Try shell_exec instead of echo exec

Comment: @Bonzo `shell_exec` works for date but not for image conversion

Comment: Try: <?php
exec("convert \"C:\bhargav\dev\download.jpg\" -resize 384 -dither FloydSteinberg -remap pattern:gray50 \"C:\bhargav\dev\con.jpg\" ");
?>

Comment: @Bonzo tried but not working