# I'm having trouble with the passthru() function when redirecting stderr to stdout

Tags: php, stderr, passthru

Could you help me with this strange passthru() behavior?

This code writes the "Division by zero" error to test.log:

```php
passthru('php -r "echo 1/0;" 2>logs/test.log >> logs/test.log');
```

But this code doesn't. It writes the error to console:

```php
passthru('php -r "echo 1/0;" 2>&1 >> logs/test.log');
```

I was expecting that the stderr is redirected also to stdout.
Is this a known issue with passthru?

I'm running this in a CLI script.

Comment: The second code also writes the error to the log file.

Comment: SHOULD write, but it doesn't :)

Comment: If you run the command directly in the terminal (rather than via passthru) does it behave as you expected?

Comment: Yes, it does, on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Redirections are processed left to right. So the second redirects stderr to the original stdout (the console), then redirects stdout to the file. So errors don't go to the file. You need to put `2>&1` after `>> logs/test.log`

Comment: Why do you use `passthru()` when all the output is being redirected? The whole point of `passthru()` is to send the command's output to the client. It's not really useful at all in CLI scripts, only web scripts.

Comment: That was the problem: "You need to put 2>&1 after >> logs/test.log". I've reversed the redirecetions and it works as expected. Thanks, @Barmar!

As regarding the user of passthru(), i don't know a simpler way to run a command in a subshell from php and show its output.

Comment: But you don't want to show its output, you're redirecting the output to a file. Use `exec()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072696/what-is-different-between-exec-shell-exec-system-and-passthru-functions