# PHP exec() or system() to call and pass value

Tags: php

I want to call an external php script that generates docx files with one of the docx php document creator I'm using.

I'm wondering if I should use `exec('/path/to/script.php $pass_var1 $pass_var2 $pass_var3 $pass_var4 $pass_var5 $pass_var6');`

or

```
system('/path/to/script.php $pass_var1 $pass_var2 $pass_var3 $pass_var4 $pass_var5 $pass_var6');
```

will it pass in the $pass_var1 into the script.php as $pass_var1? if I were to call it in the script? which one would be a better function to use for this purpose?

Comment: You should check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Comment: no, it won't, because `'`-quoted strings do not expand/interpolate variable values. you're passing literal `$`, `p`, `a`, etc... chars to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes. You need to use

```
system("/path/to/script.php $pass_var1 $pass_var2 $pass_var3 $pass_var4 $pass_var5 $pass_var6");
```

Also, you may need to use `escapeshellarg` when setting all the `$pass_varN` variables, if they come from untrusted user input.

Comment: Thank you, this was a great answer. I will make sure to use escapeshellarg although this app is internal. But you never know.

Comment: I used escapeshellarg when passing in the vars to the script and used $argv to parse the array of values which were passed in as args in the script which was called from the system() function.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to integrate the script directly in to your project using include or require. Using system() or exec() can be very dangerous, as it could allow a user of your web application to execute almost anything on your webserver.  With regards to your question, I believe it is partially answered here [What are the differences of system(), exec() and shell_exec() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828707/what-are-the-differences-of-system-exec-and-shell-exec-in-php)

Either

```
exec("php -f /path/to/script.php $params")
```

Or

```
system("php -f /path/to/script.php $params")
```

Should work

Comment: that's a good point and I would be worried if the app was facing a public domain. this is an internal app, i don't mind using it. what does the php -f flag do?

Comment: The -f flag tells it to parse and execute that file, but I suppose it also works without.