# How to ignore errors in shell_exec?

Tags: php, error-handling, shell-exec

I get the output of a shell command in PHP as

```
$str = shell_exec("command");
```

and run the PHP script in terminal. When the `shell command` returns an error, it will be printed on the terminal. How can I tell `shell_exec` to return the command output only without any error output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828773/1954610)? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to discard error output by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`

```
$str = shell_exec("command 2>/dev/null");
```

*Non-error* output - `stdout` - will be stored into `$str` as before.

---

Note that you don't need to suppress errors on `shell_exec` with the `@` operator or wrap it into a `try`-`catch` block since `shell_exec` doesn't fail (you don't have a PHP runtime error).

It is the command it is asked to execute that may generate errors, the above approach will suppress those in the output.

Also `some-command > /dev/null 2>&1` as other suggested **is not what you want** (if I understood correctly your question) since that would discard both error and *non-error* output.

---

A **final note**: you can decide to catch/discard `stdout` and/or `stderr`.

Of course you have to rely upon the fact that the command you're running send regular output to `stdout` and errors to `stderr`. If the command is not compliant to the standard (ex. sends everything to `stdout`) you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore errors of your command, you need to modify your command to redirect errors like this:

```
some-command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this too at the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

If you set 0, you won't see the errors, if you set 1 you will see all errors

Comment: Someone down-voted this but didn't say why.

Reason is simple, as the author of the accepted response stated, shell_exec() is not really failing, you don't get a PHP run-time error even if the command executed inside fails.