# How can I run a linux command from a PHP script

Tags: php, linux, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php shell_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)

How do I run a linux command from a PHP script?  I'm running Linux Debian and PHP5.  I want to be able to issue a `wget` command to the console.

An example of what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
phpFunction ("wget http://www.example.com/image.jpg /folder");
echo "done";
```

Also would I be able to echo the output of that function?

Comment: use [exec] (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) its very direct

Comment: you might want to look at the [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library to handle web requests from your script rather than using a system call to wget

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run any command. Be careful not to exec any user input though, as it can severely compromise your server.

Also, note that most shared servers block off the `exec` function so you won't be able to use it.

Finally, as a shorthand, you can wrap the command you want to exec in [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Answer (score 6):

You can do what you want with the following code :

```
system(command);
```

See http://php.net/system

Comment: The correct answer. Example: <?php   system("ls", $retval);  echo $retval; ?> get the output if any.

Comment: excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can execute linux commands within a php script - all you have to do is put the command line in backticks (`).

And also concentrate on `exec()`, this and `shell_exec()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
exec
shell_exec
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php