# How to make a php script run a specific command

Tags: php

I have a command line that I run from a specific directory to resize images, but I now need it to run from a php script so I can put it into a cron job to automate.  The command is `mogrify -resize 800x800\> *.jpg`.  I'm only looking for help to set up the php script, as I'm novice to doing this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kojiro is right - however, to answer the specific part of your question about running commands via php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 3):

Cron has nothing to do with php. Have you tried putting

```
cd "$whatever_directory" && mogrify -resize 800x800\> *.jpg
```

in cron?

That said, you can get php to execute shell commands with [`exec` and `shell_exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec), but I would urge you to consider if that's what you want.

Comment: I'm very new to doing even a basic script in php, so thank you for your response.  ...and yes, I should have been a little clearer, I meant that this php script will later be put into a cron job.  I will try your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I re-read your response to enter the code directly into cron.  WORKED PERFECT and easier than expected!  Thanks!  I guess I didn't need to setup a php script file to call from.  I am using ImageMagick on my server to process these images (I also had a misspelling:  mogrify is the correct command wording I needed too)