# How do I run a batch file from PHP that loops x times (PHP LOOP)?

Tags: php, batch-file

My nearish psuedo code: -

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
exec("C:\wamp\www\googletodaybatch.bat");
echo $i;
}
```

The bat file contains the following: -

```
START C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\googletoday-task.php"
```

I want to use this way instead of include file as I need it to start 5 instances of the task.
Each instance takes 2 mins. So I don't want it to wait. It updates many databases all at the same time.

Do I use "exec" or "shell_exec"?

**Summary: -**
Instead of having many lines in my bat file that are all the same, I want one line running many times using a loop from PHP.

Help please!
The code above seems to just keep loading and never stops....

Answer (score 0):

Use just a batch file to start the five tasks

```
for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do (
    START "" "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\googletoday-task.php" 
)
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7093860/2861476) you will find the exec vs shell_exec information.

Comment: This is great for the batch file, but maybe I should have added - it needs to run for each distinct client in the database (i.e. 5), therefore I would need to update the batch file each time.

Comment: 1. The Php get how many companys there are and passes this number to the batch file somehow....