# Get output of a php file running in background

Tags: php, background, exec

I have two php files. Let's call them `a.php` and `b.php`.

When the user visits `a.php`, I use `exec()` to execute `b.php` and `b.php` generates an output.

My question is: how can I get this output displayed at `a.php` or to another file when the process is complete in `b.php` ?

Here is my code:

```
exec("C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe C:\wamp\www\b.php 2>otst.txt");
```

Comment: exec() blocks, usually, until the exec'd process completes. that means your `a` script is dead in the water until `b` completes. but by default `exec` only returns the LAST line of output from the program. to capture everything, you need to do `exec(external_file, $output, $exit_value)`.

Comment: The OP should precise the question, in particular the term "display at" is not really appropriate for php files.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of theses 2 PHP function :

[passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) - Execute an external program and display raw output

[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)- Execute an external program and display the output

Example with System :

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('ls', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

(Source http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything fancy, you can use the [backtick](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) (`` ` ``) operator instead of `exec()`:

```
$output = `php b.php`;
```

Note that the backticks correspond to calling [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), see this related question for a discusson on [exec vs shell_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec).