# How to call R script from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, r

I have a bunch of [R scripts](https://www.r-project.org/about.html) that do some calculations and return a result. I am planning of building a PHP website that the user can actually submit a form where the data gets passed to my R script, processed and then return the result to the PHP and update the interface.

The plan is to have a database so when a user submits a form, the data gets stored in the database so R can read, process the input and then insert the result in the database so PHP can grab it. However, there are 2 problems:

1. How do my R script knows that certain values have been stored in the database so it can grab those values and do the processing?
2. When my R script finishes processing the data and insert it to mysql db, how do I get PHP to understand that at this moment PHP needs to query the database and grab the value?

Let's say my R script is like the following:

```
range<-1:20
m<-mean(range)
s<-sum(range)
print(m)
print(s)
```

As you can see the input at this case would be `1` and `20` to define the range, and the output is to show the values of `m` and `s` on my webpage.

Any idea how to accomplish that?
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) are likely your best choices in PHP. [This answer explains the difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)

```
echo shell_exec("Rscript my_script.R {$_GET['range']}");
```

Comment: So I don't need to use mysql database here?

Comment: If you need the inputs to persist across page loads, then store inputs in a database. If there is a huge amount of data in each call, and you're using the database as a way to persist the data between languages, then great (but this wasn't clear in the question). If the data is just pass-through and brief, there is no reason to involve a database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. this is helpful

Comment: Except that you always use `escapeshellarg()` to escape user input: `echo shell_exec("Rscript my_script.R " . escapeshellarg($_GET["range"]));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no r expert, but it's been done :
/ poorman.php

```
echo "
";
echo "Number values to generate: 
";
echo "Submit";
echo ""
;

if(isset($_GET['N']))
{
  $N = $_GET['N'];

  // execute R script from shell
  // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
  exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N");

  // return image tag
  $nocache = rand();
  echo("");
}
?>
```

and the R script…

## my_rscript.R

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

N <- args[1]
x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
hist(x, col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

[source](https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/)

Comment: Basically, you're telling me that I don't need a database at all?

Comment: You can execute r scripts directly, yes.

Comment: In the source, they mentioned that Only one user can be using this web app at a time.. I understand that because the R script will be busy processing the input.. how can my script be handle concurrent requests?

Comment: I am not sure of this solution, but maybe each time we generate an R script and once it's done we delete it?

Comment: @Riad re concurrency: May I suggest trying it, seeing whether there's a problem, and then opening a different question if there is? (Include your code!) You may find this isn't an issue at all.