# exec function not return the value while calling from PHP

Tags: php, node.js, unix

If I want to call/execute node test.js file into demo.php file. I found one function called **exec()** which will execute the node command into PHP.

Here is my file where I have created two files are as follow.

**test.js**

```
console.log('welcome');
```

where I have simply added the message called "welcome". Now I have created one more file for PHP where I want to call above file and print the above message while I am called below file.

**demp.php**

```
<?php
       $result = exec('node detail.js &',$out);
       print_r($result);
       print_r($out);
?>
```

Problem is that when I execute PHP file "http://localhost/demo.php" the output like below

```
Array ( )
```

and I cannot find any message in console.log.

Comment: node runs in the background because of `&` in `node detail.js &`

Comment: @hisener Oky then how may i check that file call or not and my node file message is display in console log or not..?

Comment: I am not a php guy but I found this. Please take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php It says `Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string`

Comment: @hisener ok thanks for answer but let me clear the thing is shell-exec and exec both are different function check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec