# run a command line from a symfony function

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

I like to run : php sendnotifications.php  (path : C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe sendnotifications.php) from a symfony function

```
public function reserverHebAction(Request $request,$idHebergement)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ReservationHebergement = new ReservationHebergement();
    $form = $this->createForm(ReserverType::class, $ReservationHebergement);


    $hebergement=$em->getRepository('govoyagereverseBundle:Hebergement')
        ->find($idHebergement);

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid() ){
        $hebergement->setDisponibilite($hebergement->getDisponibilite() ==0);
        $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($hebergement);//insert into model
        $em->flush();//execution de la requete

        $ReservationHebergement->setNomUtilisateurH($user);
        $ReservationHebergement->setIdhebergement($idHebergement);

        $em->persist($ReservationHebergement);
        $em->flush();
        //************sms-***************************************
        /**********I I NEED TO EXCUTE IT HERE **************
        //*******sms-*****************************

        return $this->redirectToRoute('rechercheHeb');
    }
    return $this->render(
        '@govoyagegestionHebergementAdmin/hebergement/reserverHeb.html.twig',
        array('f2' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `exec` or `shell_exec` methods to do what you're specifically asking [(here's an answer discussing the difference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec) but I would suggest importing whatever function you need and running it.

Comment: Symfony also has a [Process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for this sort of thing.  Probably overkill.

Comment: Agreed, Process is a better solution but regardless you shouldn't run a process for a `php.exe phpfile.php`

Comment: i'v add ------

        $process = new Process('/wamp64/bin/php sendnotifications.php');

            $process->run();-----

still doesn't work

Comment: is it normal that he cannot fnd declaration to go to sendnotifications.php and wamp64 ?

Comment: Error messages often make things easier to debug.  But I always like a challenge.  I suspect the php executable has no idea where sendnotifications.php is.

Comment: so what can i do ?

Comment: Have you though about using symfony console commands https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html instead ? Maybe a more clean solution for you and not very difficult.