# calling python from PHP with arguments

Tags: php, python, server, exec

I have a python script on local machine sending data to PHP script on google cloud compute engine. I want my PHP script to send that data to another python script as arguments for processing. I am trying this,
php script

```
<?php
$time = $_GET['time'];
exec("python3 caller.py ".$time,$output);
ar_dump($output);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: That's actually two different questions, please move the Python part to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to look up shell_exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
and [PHP shell_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec) ?

In addition i cant see your dir structure but php will probably require you to declare where from you execute your scripts. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

Comment: Still no luck, PHP is not calling python. using, 
shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/caller.py"); #no arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variables like below

```
$prog = 'pathtopythonfile/filename.py '.$variable1.' '.$variable2;
shell_exec($prog);
```

inside python file, u can get variables like below

```
import sys

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant add comments at the moment so you could see this as a comment:
What output do you get or do you get any errors? You're asking for help but not saying what's wrong.

Also there is a system function in php for this case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

```
$output = system("python3 caller.py ".$time, $executioncode);
```

Comment: php is not even calling python. no error, no output. Otherwise, python would have made changes in my database.