# How to execute shell command from php?

Tags: php, apache, shell, server, raspberry-pi

I have a apache server running on raspberry pi and i want to execute shell script using command through in php,

the code which is to be executed is :

```
"usr/bin/libreoffice --pt trial1 /var/www/html/Book1.xlsx"
```

how to run this command ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP shell\_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde no its not,i know the difference ,i asked this because the shell_exec() returns null when executed and nothing happens

Comment: how we know what you have tried and what not. for this you need to specified all things [read how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde okay sorry for that , do you have any clues ?

Answer (score 3):

use `shell_exec()` to run shell script.

And also make sure that exec and shell_exec is enabled in PHP ini.

Comment: yes shell_exec is enabled in php.ini but nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

use [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) built in php function  here

```
shell_exec("usr/bin/libreoffice --pt trial1 /var/www/html/Book1.xlsx")
```

you can also used built in function [exec()](https://www.phptutorial.info/?exec) or [system()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) here [see](https://www.poftut.com/execute-shell-commands-php-exec-examples/)