# Source a MySQL file through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

how do I source a .sql file, like the one below, through php?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS data_base;
USE data_base;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the_table( 
    package_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`package_name`)
)
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. I've tried to do some research and it seems I need to do something called LOAD DATA INFILE, but I don't understand it.

```
mysql_query("source C:/xampp/htdocs/Project1/mysql/source.sql;") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I source an .sql file using PHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just run an SQL script, even with mysqli::multi_query().  An SQL script can contain some commands that are recognized as [builtin commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html) only by the mysql client, not by the MySQL server's SQL parser.

`SOURCE` is definitely a command that is preprocessed by the mysql client.  The server does not understand that command.  So you can't execute `SOURCE` on the server using the query API.

If you can restrict the content of your SQL script to exclude mysql client builtin commands, it might work to use mysqli::multi_query().  But it won't work for the full set of commands that are allowed in an SQL script.

See also my answer to [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028289/20860)

LOAD DATA INFILE does not execute SQL statements to create tables, it just loads fields of a text file into an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing `mysql` command line statements with PHP functional calls. Do one or the other.

Utilize the `mysql` CLI (if available):

```
// executing mysql cli
exec("mysql < test.sql");
```

Or run the SQL with [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
// running the files contents in bulk
$sql= file_get_contents('test.sql');
mysqli_multi_query($sql);
```

**Note:** This is a potential security risk. Be advised.

Comment: The SQL file could be malicious (i.e. faked, user-generated, etc). In addition, you had limited error control with a multi-query. The point is it should be run in a very specific and limited cases.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a really old one I just stumbled across but I don't see anybody mention what I've always had work for me --NOTE I didn't look this up, just thought about it and it worked so I've used it for years, may not be the most secure way.
If the queries are already in a .sql file, I have always just read that in as a text file and passed it one line at a time with the fgets() function in php.

For example if this is in the .sql file.

```
CREATE DATABASE Testing123;
USE Testing123;
CREATE TABLE testData(name VARCHAR(32), age INT, town VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO testData(name, age, town) VALUES('Chris', 42, 'Clarksville');
```

Then uploading that from a webpage with this html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="import_sql_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" name="data"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Import"/></p>
</form>
```

The import_sql_file.php script I have always used to get it into the database looks like:

```
<?php
    $file = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");
    $fromFile = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($fromFile)){
        $query = fgets($fromFile);
        $db->query($query);
    }
    $db->close();
?>
```

Using SOURCE $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'] failed on first thought I tried, then this thought worked on the second try so I never really looked into a more direct way to do it with SQL commands.