# Execute multiple .sql files from directory

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have one direcory who contain 1000 (.sql) files, am trying to make php script to pull all that files in sql.

This look like this etc..

> 2013_07_17_00_world_version.sql 2013_07_17_01_world_conditions.sql
>   2013_07_17_02_world_gossip.sql 2013_07_17_03_world_gossip.sql
>   2013_07_17_04_world_spell_script_names.sql
>   2013_07_18_00_world_conditions.sql 2013_07_18_01_world_koralon.sql
>   2013_07_18_02_world_spell_script_names.sql
>   2013_07_18_02_world_the_flesh_giant_slayer.sql
>   2013_07_18_03_world_equipment.sql 2013_07_19_00_world_misc.sql
>   2013_07_20_00_world_gameobject.sql 2013_07_20_01_world_misc.sql
>   2013_07_23_00_world_misc.sql 2013_07_23_02_world_creature_template.sql
>   2013_07_24_00_world_spell_script_names.sql
>   2013_07_24_01_world_spell_ranks_335.sql
>   2013_07_24_02_world_trinity_strings.sql
>   2013_07_24_03_world_spell_proc_event_335.sql
>   2013_07_25_00_world_spell_script_names.sql

My strategy is first to take file name and put that name in query but i do somthing wrong. Any1 have idea or softwere how can pull multy..

my code is :

```
<?php

$path = 'updates/world';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'socvbe';
$host = 'localhost';
$base = 'world';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($base) or die(mysql_error());


if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
           //echo "$entry\n<br>";
            mysql_query($entry) or die('error in query');

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want execute multiple .sql files

Comment: @Ikac but what is the problem with your code? Any error?

Comment: Yeah... no, that doesn't help. What is the *specific* problem with the code you've written?

Comment: You can't do that, `$entry` is just the name of the file, not a query.  Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php

Answer (score 0):

php isn't smart enough to know that you want to read the contents of your .sql files and use that contents as the queries to mysql. Currently you are sending filenames to mysql_query but it expects an sql query.  First you need to get the queries from the file by either opening it with fopen and reading with fread or by using the file_get_contents function.

See [here](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to use file_get_contents

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to use fopen/fread