# Execute a SQL script by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code that I am currently using, but it's not working:

```
$param=$_GET['param'];
echo $param;
$query =file_get_contents($param);
```

Comment: **What is not working?** You are just loading a file - you need to do some action on it if you want SQL to "execute".

Comment: you need to use database driver as [mysql](http://php.net/mysqli) to do that

Comment: `file_get_contents` just __gets contents of a file__

Comment: Uhm this isn't SQL...

Comment: Actually I want to get as $query =file_get_contents("D:\MyScript.sql"); Here I want to pass this location from c#.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain what you are trying to do. The more details you provide the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: this is the result while running.                                             "D:\Myscript.sql"
Warning: file_get_contents("D:\\Myscript.sql"): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: @fidha are you running the webserver on your local computer? Altough, even if you are, you might have access issues too.

Comment: yes,am using local computer webserver for this..                                                                       http://localhost:5445/RunPhp/create.php?action=ExecuteScript&file="D:\Myscript.sql"

Comment: $query =file_get_contents($param);                                                                                         i need instead of param                                                                                                          $query =file_get_contents("D:\Myscript.sql");                                                   to execute ?any solutions plz

Comment: //Warning: file_get_contents("D:\Myscript.sql"): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\RunPhp\create.php

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment

> Actually I want to get as $query
>   =file_get_contents("D:\MyScript.sql"); Here I want to pass this location from c#

you should just read the content from the file with some kind of filereader and then execute the file with a instance of your db. I'm not pretty sure why you wrote "execute the script by php" and your comment says "pass the location from c#" but the base solution should be the same.

Comment: $query =file_get_contents($param); i need instead of param. $query =file_get_contents("D:\Myscript.sql"); to execute ?any solutions plz

Comment: Maybe this one can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php

Comment: $param=$_GET['file'];
echo $param;
 
$query =file_get_contents($param);//here i need $query =file_get_contents("D:\Myscript.sql");
$sqlArray = explode(';',$query );

Comment: //Warning: file_get_contents("D:\Myscript.sql"): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\RunPhp\create.php

Comment: I think your problem is using the double quotes at your path. If you use them you should put "D:\\Myscript.sql" and if you don't want to use them use single quotes like 'D:\Myscript.sql'

Comment: Even if i ignore the fact that it seems i can't get it plain again (what i actually don't want to do at this point) i don't get it working to encrypt a password and decrypt it using the password and the hash.

Comment: ("D:\Myscript.sql" )this path getted  from c# by passed a string and it is call in php code as $param,but while calling this                                          $query =file_get_contents($param),not opening..!                                         but $query =file_get_contents("D:\MyScript.sql") this is working .                         but i need this php code for many times so passing strings is good for me ,but it is not working