# .sql file execution using php and pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to run a .sql file using PHP and PDO.

It is working fine in my local environment. But in live it executes only 3500 lines from my SQL file.

Below this is my PHP code:

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/');
define('DIR_URL', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$db_username,$db_pass);
$sql = file_get_contents(SITE_URL.'database/mysql.sql');
$db->exec($sql);
```

My problem is `mysql.sql` file is executing only 3500 lines after that it does not execute the remaining lines in live environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running MySQL \*.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php)

Comment: Maximum execution time ?

Comment: @RantoRasolomahefa its already set to  set_time_limit(0);

Comment: @NigelRen my problem is file execution not work after  3500 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using [this script](https://gist.github.com/b4oshany/0698d9f32589b77abdcb) my `mysql.sql` file imported successfully.

Thanks to [Oshane Bailey](https://gist.github.com/b4oshany)