# MySQL: Is it possible to give mysql username and password in single line?

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, passwords

Can we connect database by terminal by one line. because i'm trying to connect MySQL by terminal from PHP `exec()`. Here i want to import one MySQL file so i tried following code but it asks password on execution time. so i need help. I want to connect db in one line with username and password.

```sh
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: WHY??? You can access a MySQL database from the PHP code direct, much more efficiently and without the complexity of an `exec()` call

Comment: yes but the problem is i need to execute one big .sql file in another database. Here i'm using codeigniter framework. The problem is we are creating that another database in this process only.

Comment: Then import it and execute it line by line. Using `exec()` is usually a bad idea if you can avoid it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling MySQL exe using PHP exec doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814586/calling-mysql-exe-using-php-exec-doesnt-work)

Comment: If it is a big sql file, then access MySQL directly from cli or a proper desktop client, not through php.

Comment: Is there multiple databases or only one password. I haven't tested but I think .my.cnf could work here also. Look https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/mycnf-preference

Comment: I got. Following is working fine. mysql -u usernmae -p'password' dbname < file.sql

Answer (score 3):

mysql -h your_host -u your_username -pyour_password -P your_port dbname

`-p` and `your_password` without space.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This worked for me. Note that `-p` and `your_password` are without any space.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful while doing such kinds of operations. I am giving you one of the solutions to import your database in a single line.

1- Create one configuration file which includes user and password of the database.

**[client]user=root password=redhat**

2-Fire this command  **mysql --defaults-extra-file= pathtothenewconfig file [all my other options]**

**mysql --defaults-extra-file=db.php databasename  < /home/pratikesh/Downloads/localdb.sql**

Hopes it will works